# Remove "Server" header using mono and Owin selfhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mono, self-hosting

I'm hosting my mono WebApi project in a simple console application:

```
WebApp.Start<Test>("http://localhost:1234/")
```

When I get a response from the server, the "Server" header is always included, I can't find a way to remove it.

e.g. Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Mono source code,

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListenerResponse.cs

if you don't set a `Server` header on your own, Mono will set the default `Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0` for you. Thus, to avoid seeing the default, set a `Server` header using your own string.